# jquery fill input form with url data

Tags: jquery

how i need fill out a input of my form with jquery.

I have my url: http://example.com/page.html?name=YourName=Mark

Comment: If English is not your native language, try using http://translate.google.com/ to help turn this into a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function that returns the value of a querystring parameter and then set the form field accordingly:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
 }

var sName = getParameterByName(name);
```

Then set the form field value using jquery:

```
$("#formFieldID").val(sName);
```

Comment: your querystring would look something like this

http://example.com/page.html?name=Mark